# Fetching data from firebase without calling own data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tinder type set up and I am fetching all of the users so I can swipe on their cards. everything works smoothly except for the fact that this swipe view is also calling the data from the current user allowing them to swipe on themselves. This should not happen.

The code that I am using is

func fetchUser() {

```
     topCardView = nil
     var previousCardView: CardView?
    Database.database().reference().child("jobPost").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let poster = Poster(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
                let cardView = self.setupCardFromUser(poster: poster)
                self.cardViewModels.append(poster.toCardViewModel())

                if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
                    currentUser == poster.fromId {
                    cardView.removeFromSuperview()
                    } else if self.topCardView == nil {
                      self.topCardView = cardView
                    }

                previousCardView?.nextCardView = cardView
                previousCardView = cardView

        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

This allows me to call all of the data from firebase however, it is also calling the currentUsers data as well.

I thought that maybe if were to use

```
  let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

   if currentUser == cardView {
     cardView?.removeFromSuperview()

    }
```

would do the job but on this, I am receiving error

Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'CardView'

does anyone know a quick fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your cardView have information about user?
Maybe you can add userID field to the card view ?
if it's possible , you will be able to do something like this

```
if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
  let cardView = cardView,
  currentUser == cardView.userID {
  // put your code to ignore card
}
```

where userId - will be string type

Comment: Thanks for your comment this worked! It's giving me a little glitch but it does do what I am looking for

Comment: glitched was fixed to what it is above.